# How to invoke a Workflow Activity with PowerShell script?

Tags: shell, powershell, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

How can I start up a workflow (contained in a custom assembly) by using a PowerShell script?

Comment: Load the assembly with Add-Type and then start the workflow the same way you would do from, say, c# code.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj619280.aspx